# i am trying to modify this case statement in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop, calculated-field

CASE
WHEN [Metric Type] = 'FTE' THEN 'Per Student FTE'
WHEN [Metric Type] = 'GSF' THEN 'Per GSF'
ELSE NULL
END

I am getting an error message that an identifier is missing. how can I modify this expression using the correct syntax for Tableau desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct syntax.

```
CASE [Metric Type]
  WHEN "FTE" THEN "Per Student FTE"
  WHEN "GSF" THEN "Per GSF"
END
```

Note - in this case, it looks like you are using the calculated field simply to provide a more human readable label. In that case, there is a simpler alternative - use an *alias*. Select the field Metric Type in the data pane (left margin) and use right click to set any aliases you like.

Aliases are simple translation tables for specifying strings to display for various values. They allow you to use short efficient codes in your database, say "M" or "F", and still use more descriptive text when displaying, say "Male" or "Female"

Defining aliases for a field is similar to defining default number or date formats. They don't impact how a value is represented internally, just how it is displayed. (The primary exception to that statement is when you are writing calculations that pull from multiple data sources using data blending - in that case, those late stage calculations see the aliases instead of the original values. But that's a relatively uncommon issue)